# angular controller doesnt get called or instantiated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I am trying to call a function in another controller from a different controller but but I keep getting error

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'NewCaseCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

My app.js

```
.state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })

  .state('app.dashboard', {
    url: "/dashboard",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/dashboard.html",
      }
    }
  })

.state('app.new', {
    url: "/new_referral",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/new_referral.html",
        controller: 'NewCaseCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

my dashboard.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Dashboard">
  <ion-content>
    <div class="list card">
      <div class="item bar bar-royal">Referral Case Updates</div>
        <div class="item item-body">
                <div ng-controller="NewCaseCtrl" class="ion-ios-plus-outline" ng-click="createNew()"></div>
      </div>
    </div>      
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

my new_referral.html

```
<ion-view view-title="New Referral">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-small" ng-click = "goBack()">Cancel</button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>  
  </ion-nav-bar>
  <ion-content>
<p> In new referral page
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

my new_controller.js

```
angular.module('my.controllers')
.controller('NewCaseCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $q, $window, $ionicModal, createNewRealEstateCase, $state, $ionicLoading, $cordovaCamera, $cordovaFile, $cordovaFileTransfer, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {
   $scope.createNew = function() {
    console.log("in here build loan application")
    createNewRealEstateCase.buildLoanApplication().then(function(data){
      $rootScope.states = data.states;
      $rootScope.nationalities = data.nationalities;

      var hideSheet = $ionicActionSheet.show({
      buttons: [
       { text: 'Eligibility Checking' },
       { text: 'Loan Application' }
      ],
      cancelText: 'Cancel',
      titleText: 'Type of Service',

      cancel: function() {
          // add cancel code..
      },
      buttonClicked: function(index) {
        console.log(index)
        if(index == 0) {
          $scope.eligibility = true;
        }
        else if(index == 1){
          $scope.eligibility = false;
        }
        $state.go('app.new')
        return true;
      }
    });

    $timeout(function() {
      hideSheet();
    }, 10000);

    });
  };
});
```

Why do i get an error why i click on the `createNew()` div in dashboard.html when i have already initiated ng-controller="NewCaseCtrl"? why doesnt it work as it should?

Thanks any help appreciated

Comment: Please also show how u have defined ng-app on html!

Comment: it is defined. @NitinVarpe

Comment: where is the code ng-app="appname"? please show that code

Comment: its in my index.html page.

Comment: is it like this? ng-app="my.controllers"?

Comment: i have solved my issue @NitinVarpe thanks for the 1million questions

Answer (score 0):

Instead of nesting controllers you can have a service which shares the data & functions for both the controller.

Comment: done tht bt still same error when ever i do $state.go('app.new') i get an error immediately